# a href tag not working with in script

Tags: php, html, href

I am working on a script now i am facing the problem with  tag.
my code is below. I don't know what's wrong with my code because my link is not working.

```
<select size="5" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
<?php
  while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
   extract($row); 
   ?>
<p class="notice">


              <?php
if($row['userPic']) { ?>

<option><a href="uploads/<?php echo $row['userPic']; ?>"><?php echo $headline ?></a></option>
<?php } 
else { ?>
    <?php echo '<option>'.$headline.'</option>'; ?>
    <?php } ?>

</p>  
<?php 
} ?> </select>
```

Comment: What does the produced html look like?

Comment: does it work with echo $userPic; instead of $row['userPic']  ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: As Benoti says use `$userPic` as you have extracted the `$row` array

Comment: I got the following output in viewsource.
<select size="5" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
<p class="notice">
<option><a href="uploads/963425.jpg">Students_elections_2016_8</a></option>
</p>  
</select>